# How to append to a json object in angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, append

I am having an object like this `$scope.releases = [{name : "All Stage",active:true}];`

I need to append more data to it

```
[
  {name : "Development",active:false},
  {name : "Production",active:false},
  {name : "Staging",active:false}
]
```

So the final data should be like this

```
[
   {name : "All Stage",active:true}
   {name : "Development",active:false},
   {name : "Production",active:false},
   {name : "Staging",active:false}
]
```

I tried the following code. But it is not appending.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  // I am having an object like this
  $scope.releases = [{name : "All Stage",active:true}];
  // I need to appned some more data to it
  $scope.releases = [
    {name : "Development",active:false},
    {name : "Production",active:false},
    {name : "Staging",active:false}
  ]
});
```

Pluker Link : http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:3510140

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
  $scope.releases = [{name : "All Stage",active:true}];
  // Concatenate the new array onto the original
  $scope.releases = $scope.releases.concat([
    {name : "Development",active:false},
    {name : "Production",active:false},
    {name : "Staging",active:false}
  ]);
```

Comment: when i am trying this i got the following error `TypeError: $scope.releases.concat is not a function`

Comment: @Ambal Mani - `$scope.releases` is not an array at the point you're trying to call `concat` on it. What's the result of `typeof($scope.releases)` ?

Answer (score 5):

Just use the [Array concat method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp)

```
$scope.release = [{name : "All Stage",active:true}];
$scope.releases = [
    {name : "Development",active:false},
    {name : "Production",active:false},
    {name : "Staging",active:false}
];
$scope.releases = $scope.releases.concat($scope.release);
```

Answer (score 1):

user angular.extend() to extend the object
[angular extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

you can also use angular.merge() [angular merge](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge)

Comment: useful for merging object and not just arrays in a simple way. voted up because of usefulness even if sightly ot

Comment: angular merge is now deprecated