# Adding ng-model values as grouped children in array

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Learning python has made me forget all my angular, and that's my story and I'm sticking to it. It's even made me forget my google skills, since I can't find a similar question anywhere. The closest might be [How to append to a json object in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070790/how-to-append-to-a-json-object-in-angular-js), except that didn't work, either.

I've got ten sets of two input fields, title and description. I want to add them as children to an array, so I'll end up with ten properties in my json, and each property in turn has two children properties. I've tried push, concat, even the old-fashioned += in desperation, but nothing's working. I must be totally missing the obvious.

Here's what each row looks like, though the numbers change (from 1 to 10):

```
<label class="sr-only" for="shorttitle1">short title</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-click="addIdea()" ng-model="idea1.title" placeholder="title">
<label class="sr-only" for="description1">description</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-click="addIdea()" ng-model="idea1.description" placeholder="description">
```

In my controller, here's the version I've tried based on the link above, which isn't working any better than concat or push did:

```
$scope.ideas = [
        {idea : $scope.idea1.title, $scope.idea1.description},
        {idea : $scope.idea2.title, $scope.idea2.description},
        {idea : $scope.idea3.title, $scope.idea3.description}
];
```

I keep getting an error of unexpected token for the dots (as in, the dot in $scope-dot-idea1). When I put in simple text as a test, I get an unexpected token error for the closing bracket.

I've even tried doing a watchCollection, just to see if the controller would pay attention, but I'm getting nothing from that. I've tried watching just idea1, then $scope.idea1, then $scope.idea1.title, and the watchCollection just sits there.

This is what I want it to end up looking like, roughly:

```
$scope.ideas = [
    {
        type : 'title goes here',
        description : 'description goes here'
    },{
        type : 'title goes here',
        description : 'description goes here'
    },{
        type : 'title goes here',
        description : 'description goes here'
    }
];
```

I've checked the really obvious -- ng-app isn't on the same level as ng-controller, I'm calling the right controller, I don't have any wacky misspellings.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

You missed the description key off your object definitions.

```
$scope.ideas = [
    {idea : $scope.idea1.title, desc: $scope.idea1.description},
    {idea : $scope.idea2.title, desc: $scope.idea2.description},
    {idea : $scope.idea3.title, desc: $scope.idea3.description}
];
```

Comment: well, that cleared out one problem, and let me discover the *real* problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after getting one problem out of the way thanks to @BenCr, I discovered the real issue. It's in here:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-click="addIdea()" ng-model="idea1.title" placeholder="title">
```

There's no name. For whatever reason, you have to have a name that matches the ng-model, and then angular will play nice. I'm so used to having ids and names for traditional validation, and I'm not sure why I forgot them this time. But once I added that back in, everything behaved.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="idea1title" name="idea1title" placeholder="title">
```

The other detail was that you can't have a form name like idea-dot-title-one; you have to take the dot out. Ng-model can handle it, but name can't, and the two have to match.

Comment: That's unlikely to be the real answer. Look at the two lines. First example `ng-click="addIdea()" ng-model="idea1.title"`, second example `ng-model="idea1title"`. I've got loads of controls that don't have a name. I'm glad you've fixed your solution but I don't think you've really fully understood how you've fixed it. Remove the name and try again.

Comment: I got rid of the ng-click; it wasn't doing anything. When I remove the name, fail. When I make name different from ng-model, fail. When I add a dot to name to match ng-model, fail. The only time it works is when name = ng-model, AND name is present.

Comment: Look at this example which binds input controls to objects in a list http://plnkr.co/edit/t3sSh1RPzVeeWRy9ybLj?p=preview You can see that the field names are unrelated to the name of the property in the model.