# How to append object into existing object Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have two object one is for just to hold answer of one question and another is final object. like

```
  answer = {"value":"asda","indicator":"good"};
  final = {}  ;
```

i want to append answer object to final object  like this

```
final = {{"value":"asda","indicator":"good"},{"value":"sdad","indicator":"worse"}}
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: please insert your tried code..

Comment: final is not object i think

Comment: I think it is the same with a question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070790/how-to-append-to-a-json-object-in-angular-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070790/how-to-append-to-a-json-object-in-angular-js)

Comment: yes @Mahi agreed, final has to be array

Comment: this is not possible how i am trying here ? @Mahi

Comment: no it's not possible . final should be array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly append an object. Instead, you need to hold object in an array like following.

```
answer = {"value":"asda","indicator":"good"};
final = [];
newObject = {"value":"sdad","indicator":"worse"};
```

now you can push both object to array like -

```
final.push(answer);
final.push(newObject);
```

Result of this will be -

```
final = [{"value":"asda","indicator":"good"},{"value":"sdad","indicator":"worse"}];
```

Comment: your answer is not correct because question is 'how-to-append-object-into-existing-object-angularjs?'. You created an array of 2 objects.

Answer (score 3):

```
var answer = {"value":"asda","indicator":"good"};

var final = [] //declare it as Array.

final = final.concat(answer);
```

**Updated answer :**

With **ecma6**,its can done using [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
var answer = {"value":"asda","indicator":"good"};
final = {{"value":"sdad","indicator":"worse"}}   
final  = {...final,answer };//final as an object
```

OR

```
var answer = {"value":"asda","indicator":"good"}; 
final = {{"value":"sdad","indicator":"worse"}}   
final  = [...final,answer ]; //final as an array.
```

Comment: Thanks man, the declaration as an array is crucial.

Answer (score 1):

In order to append answer object into final , final must be an array

```
var final =[];
final.push({"value":"asda","indicator":"good"}) 
or
final.push(answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your using ES2015 you could do

```
const answer = {"value":"asda","indicator":"good"};
const final = [].concat(Object.assign({}, answer))
```

Or Ghazanfar' is also valid